# Why does it make sense to write str.split(line) over line.split()?

Tags: python, string, oop

For str.split(line) I'm calling a method on the str class and passing a line object, which happens to be a list full of strings, to the string object?

It seems more clear to me that I should just call the split() method on my line object.

I'm having trouble understanding why both ways work.

Comment: @AlexThornton: No, when called as an unbound method, its first argument is the string to be split itself (the `self`).

Comment: The first sentence in the question seems wrong. If `line` is a list full of strings, both `str.split(line)` and `line.split()` are going to raise exceptions (a `TypeError`, because a list isn't a str, and an `AttributeError`, because lists don't have a `split` method, respectively). I assume you meant that `line` is a single string _within_ a list full of strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you're right that in this case, it's more readable (and more Pythonic, etc.) to just call `line.split()` than `str.split(line)`.

But are there any cases where `str.split` is useful? Sure. Imagine that you had a list of lines, and you wanted to split all of them. Which of these is more readable:

```
split_lines = map(str.split, lines)
split_lines = map(lambda line: line.split(), lines)
```

Because `str.split` is already a function that works on any `str`, you don't have to create a new function that works on any `str` to pass around.

---

More generally, what you're asking is why Python has "unbound methods".* Partly it's because they just naturally fall out of the design for how methods work in Python.** But mainly, it's because they're handy for passing around to higher-order functions (and because of the idea that absolutely everything should be usable as a value unless there's a good reason not to allow it).

---

As for the the last part, understanding how they both work, that might be a little involved for an SO answer. You can learn the basics of how they work [in the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects); for more details, see [How methods work](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-methods-work.html), which has links to other useful information. But as a quick summary:

- `line.split` is a bound method—a callable object that knows what value to pass as the `self` parameter when you later call it. So, `line.split()` just calls that bound method with no additional arguments, and `line` automatically gets passed as the `self`.
- `str.split` is an unbound method—basically just a function. So, `str.split(line)` explicitly passes `line` as the `self`.

---

<sub>* Since 3.x, the term "unbound method" has been downplayed, because really, an unbound method is the same thing as a function.</sub>

<sub>** Guido has explained this a few times; start with his 2009 blog post [First-Class Everything](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-class-everything.html).</sub>